# How to add every word at the end of the every line ? word and lines are in different txt file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

My file contains some urls in urls.txt
Another file contains some different words in words.txt

I need to be add every word at the end of the every url.

I want output like   (line by line)

```
url.1/hi
url.1/hello
url.1/there
url.2/hi
url.2/hello
url.2/there
url.3/hi
url.3/hello
url.3/there
```

I just want single line command :)

like

```
urls.txt + words.txt >> output.txt
```

Comment: The problem looks easy, but please add what you've tried. What problem do you have during your programming? There is no `cat Requirement | StackOverflow.com > workDone` service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
cat words.txt
hi
hello
there

cat urls.txt
url.1
url.2
url.3
```

You can use `awk` this way:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{words[++cnt]=$1; next}
    {for (i=1; i<=cnt; i++) print $1 words[i]}
' words.txt urls.txt
```

Prints:

```
url.1hi
url.1hello
url.1there
url.2hi
url.2hello
url.2there
url.3hi
url.3hello
url.3there
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed & Parallel)

```
parallel echo "{1}{2}" :::: urlsFile :::: wordsFile
```

or

```
sed 's@.*@echo "&" | sed "s#.*#&\&#" wordsFile@e' urlsFile
```